# What should I implement to have a custom class behave exactly as an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have a custom class, what should I override to get array-like behaviour? I think that supplying an `each` method won't be enough, as that won't give me acces to the `[]` methods?

Should I inherit the Array class? What should I overwrite in there?

Comment: Congrats for wanting to do it the right way around. Too many people first think of monkey-patching array to add their custom functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For enumerable like behavior (which sounds like what you want), you should `include Enumerable` to get the `Enumerable` module functionality, which means you need to provide a method `each`. This will give you lots of the relevant methods you want ([Enumerable details](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html)).

If you want just `[]` like functionality, you only need the following methods, and nothing more:

```
def [] key
  # return value for key here.
end

def []= key, value
  # store value under key here.
end
```

Comment: An array providers both `[]` methods, and enumerable functionality. So maybe I should consider adding both `each` and these 2 accessor methods?

Comment: Yep, if that's what you're after then provide `each`, `[]`, `[]=` and `include Enumerable`.

Comment: Is there any advantage of this approach vs. subclassing Array?

Comment: It depends. Can you say that "<your object> *is an* Array?" If so, make it a subclass of the Array, because you need all that functionality. If all you can say is "<your object> is like an array in some ways, because it supports `[]`", then just support `[]` and don't subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting from Array makes perfect sense.  You get to extend Array behavior without worrying about interactions with other users of the Array type, and you don't even need to do the trivial work to mix in Enumerable.

And if you need hooks, which you probably do, you can just call `super()` to forward the current message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an actual array that stores your data, you may want to have

```
require "forwardable"

class CustomArray
  extend Forwardable # For def_delegators
  include Enumerable # Optional

  def_delegators :@actual_array, :[], :[]=, :each

  def initialize(actual_array)
    @actual_array = actual_array
  end
end
```

By using delegation, you only provide the methods that you know you want, rather than providing all the methods by default.